# Automating Visual Studio instance from separate process

Tags: c#, visual-studio, automation

Is there a way to write an application that can connect to a running instance of Visual Studio and issue commands to it? For example, could I write a WPF app with a button that, when clicked, issues a "Build.BuildSolution" command to an already-open instance of Visual Studio, causing it to start a build?

I'm sure I could use SendKeys to send Ctrl+Shift+B, but I want to know if there's a way to write to an actual API to automate Visual Studio, and invoke commands by name.

Comment: Why not just make a Visual Studio add-in? If even to listen for those commands on a named pipe.

Comment: I probably could make a VS add-in if that's the only way to do it, but I'd feel silly going to that much pain, and restarting VS that many times, if there's already a way to automate VS from outside.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a C# program that connects to a running Visual Studio and issues a Build command.  The `DTE.9` part means "Visual Studio 2008" - use `DTE.8` for VS 2005, or `DTE.10` for VS 2010.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using EnvDTE80;

namespace SORemoteBuild
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Get an instance of the currently running Visual Studio IDE.
            EnvDTE80.DTE2 dte2;
            dte2 = (EnvDTE80.DTE2)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.
                                      GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.9.0");
            dte2.Solution.SolutionBuild.Build(true);
        }
    }

    public class MessageFilter : IOleMessageFilter
    {
        // ... Continues at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228772.aspx
```

(The nonsense with STAThread and MessageFilter is "due to threading contention issues between external multi-threaded applications and Visual Studio", whatever that means. Pasting in the code from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228772.aspx makes it work.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to automate builds/packaging of your apps, you should look into [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wea2sca5(VS.80).aspx) -- it is Microsoft's build engine that lets you script automation of most of the functions of Visual Studio.

Comment: Yes, but (a) I want Visual Studio to know it's been rebuilt so that a subsequent Run would start immediately, and (b) Build was just an example -- it's not the only command I want to issue. I also eventually want to query things out of VS, like editor save status and so on. But a simple question like "issue commands by name" seemed like the best place to start.