# How can I tell a running Visual Studio 2012 instance to run a certain macro from within a VBScript invoked by another application?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, vbscript

I have two different solutions (A and B) open inside two different instances of the Visual Studio 2012.

I want to write two macros - MacroA and MacroB. MacroA should be run on the VS instance with the solution A and MacroB - on the VS instance with the solution B.

Here is what I want to do from MacroA:

1. Start a Stopwatch
2. Trigger the build of the current solution (which is A)
3. Once the build is complete stop the Stopwatch and output the elapsed time
4. Tell the other VS instance to run MacroB

Here is what I want to do from MacroB:

1. Start a Stopwatch
2. Trigger the build of the current solution (which is B)
3. Stop the Stopwatch and output the elapsed time

Please, note that I perfectly aware of how to build a solution on the command line using devenv (or msbuild). I explicitly want to build from the IDE.

Is it possible to do what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved this problem with the help of the following resources:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7984/Automating-a-specific-instance-of-Visual-Studio-NE
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.outputwindowpane.textdocument.aspx
- [Automating Visual Studio instance from separate process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267827/automating-visual-studio-instance-from-separate-process)

Here is what I did.

**1. An auxiliary .NET exe**

Here is the source code:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;
using EnvDTE;

namespace VSInstanceFinder
{
    public static class Program
    {
        [DllImport("ole32.dll")]
        public static extern int GetRunningObjectTable(int reserved, out IRunningObjectTable prot);

        [DllImport("ole32.dll")]
        public static extern int CreateBindCtx(int reserved, out IBindCtx ppbc);

        public static DTE Find(string solutionFilePath)
        {
            var numFetched = new IntPtr();
            IRunningObjectTable runningObjectTable;
            IEnumMoniker monikerEnumerator;
            var monikers = new IMoniker[1];

            GetRunningObjectTable(0, out runningObjectTable);
            runningObjectTable.EnumRunning(out monikerEnumerator);
            monikerEnumerator.Reset();

            while (monikerEnumerator.Next(1, monikers, numFetched) == 0)
            {
                IBindCtx ctx;
                CreateBindCtx(0, out ctx);

                object runningObjectVal;
                runningObjectTable.GetObject(monikers[0], out runningObjectVal);

                var dte = runningObjectVal as DTE;
                try
                {
                    if (dte != null && dte.Solution != null && string.Equals(dte.Solution.FullName, solutionFilePath, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        return dte;
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        public static OutputWindowPane GetBuildOutputPane(object o)
        {
            try
            {
                var dte = (DTE)o;
                var outputWindow = (OutputWindow)dte.Windows.Item("{34E76E81-EE4A-11D0-AE2E-00A0C90FFFC3}").Object;

                for (var i = 1; i <= outputWindow.OutputWindowPanes.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (outputWindow.OutputWindowPanes.Item(i).Name.Equals("Build", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        return outputWindow.OutputWindowPanes.Item(i);
                    }
                }

                return outputWindow.OutputWindowPanes.Add("Build");
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public static string GetBuildLog(object o)
        {
            try
            {
                var buildOutputPane = o as OutputWindowPane;
                if (buildOutputPane == null || buildOutputPane.TextDocument == null)
                {
                    return "";
                }
                var sel = buildOutputPane.TextDocument.Selection;
                if (sel == null)
                {
                    return "";
                }
                sel.StartOfDocument();
                sel.EndOfDocument(true);
                return sel.Text;

            }
            catch
            {
                return "";
            }
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length > 0)
            {
                var dte = Find(args[0]);
                if (dte != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(GetBuildLog(GetBuildOutputPane(dte)));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**2. Powershell**

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile('C:\utils\VSInstanceFinder.exe')
function buildOneIDE([int]$i, [string]$ts, [string]$solution)
{
  $solutionFilePath = "$(Get-Location)\$solution.sln"
  $dte = [VSInstanceFinder.Program]::Find($solutionFilePath)
  if (!$dte)
  {
    Write-Host "$solutionFilePath does not seem to be open in any of the running Visual Studio instances"
    exit 1
  }
  $buildOutputPane = [VSInstanceFinder.Program]::GetBuildOutputPane($dte)

  $sw = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch
  $logFileName = "c:\tmp\logs\ui.$i.$solution.$ts.log"
  $sw.Start()
  $dte.Solution.SolutionBuild.Build($true)
  $sw.Stop()
  [VSInstanceFinder.Program]::GetBuildLog($buildOutputPane) > $logFileName
  "Elapsed Total: $([int]$sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds) seconds" >> $logFileName
  $logFile = dir $logFileName
  "$($logFile.Length)`t$($logFile.FullName)"
}
buildOneIDE 1 $(get-date -Format "yyyyMMddHHmmss") "DataSvc"
```

Does what I need.