# Automating Visual Studio from MATLAB

Tags: matlab, visual-studio, automation, activex

I want to automate a running instance of Visual Studio with MATLAB, similar to the way done in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267827/automating-visual-studio-instance-from-separate-process) in C#. I know how to create a new instance with

```
hCOM = actxserver('VisualStudio.DTE.9.0');
```

and then use it, and make it visible and usable after automation is complete as explained [here](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2005/mz2005005.aspx). What I don't know is how to connect to an existing instance of Visual Studio. How can this be accomplished in MATLAB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try the same approach I use to get a running instance of Excel:

```
hCOM = actxGetRunningServer('VisualStudio.DTE.9.0');
hCOM.Visible = 1; %OR if it does not work:
hCOM.MainWindow.Visible = 1; %As in the link provided
```

Comment: Excellent! I was looking under "COM Objects" rather than "Call MATLAB COM Automation Server" in R2013b documentation, which is why I overlooked this function. These sections seem to have been merged in the [updated online documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/using-com-objects-in-matlab.html). Thank you.